# Перевод из инфиксной нотации в обратную польскую нотацию на Питон

Tags: python, алгоритм, стек

Мне надо чтобы переводил из инфиксной нотации в обратную польскую нотацию.Unittest не проходит,выдает ексепшн.

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: tests (__main__.MyTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python_code\learnMy\tests_compilMy_package.py", line 12, in tests
    self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("( 125 * ( ( 131 + 48 ) / 35 ) ) / 7.9  ;")),['125', '131', '48', '+', '35', '/', '*', '7.9', '/'])
  File "d:\Python_code\learnMy\compilMy\compilMy.py", line 50, in opn
    token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Сам перевод:

```
#compilMy.py (как пакет)
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def tokenze(code:str)->list:
    return code.split() 
def op_prior(char_op:str):
    if char_op=="^":
        return 6
    elif char_op=="*":
        return 5
    elif char_op=="/":
        return 5
    elif char_op=="%":
        return 3
    elif char_op=="+":
        return 2
    elif char_op=="-":
        return 2

def isOp(c:str)->bool:
    if c=="-" or c=="+" or c=="*" or c=="/" or c=="^":return True
    return False

#DOES NOT WORK
def opn(code:list)->list: 
    p=0
    op_stack:list=[]
    res:list=[]
    while True: 
        v=code[p]
        p+=1
        if v==';':
            break 
        if re.match("[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*",v) or re.match("[A-Z]+[a-z]+",v):
            res.append(v)
        elif isOp(v):#i -бинарная операция
            token_tmp=''#смотрим на вверх стека

            if len(op_stack)>0:
                token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]#смотрим на вверх стека
                while(len(op_stack)>0 and isOp(token_tmp)):#пока стек >0
                    if (op_prior(v)<=op_prior(token_tmp)):#сравнием приоритет токена в строке и приоритет операци  в стеке операций
                        res.append(op_stack.pop())#если в стеке операция выше,то выталкиваем его в выходную строку
                    else:#bиначе выходим из данного цикла
                        break     
            op_stack.append(v)#тогда выйдя из цикла,добавим операцию в стек        
        elif v=='(':
           op_stack.append(v)
        elif v==')':#закрывающая )
            token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]#смотрим на вверх стека
            while (token_tmp!='(' or len(op_stack)>1):
                    res.append(op_stack.pop())
                    token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
                    if token_tmp=='(':
                       op_stack.pop()                                  
                    #if (len(op_stack)==0):
                        #raise RuntimeError("No left paren")                                                          

    while len(op_stack)>0 :
        token_tmp=op_stack[len(op_stack)-1]
        if token_tmp=="(":
            raise RuntimeError("No right paren")
        res.append(op_stack.pop())

    return res
```

Тесты:

```
#tests_compilMy_package.py
import unittest as u
from compilMy.compilMy import opn,tokenze
class MyTests(u.TestCase):
    def tests(self):
        self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("1.0 + 2.0 ;")),['1.0','2.0','+'])
        self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("1 + 2 + 4 ;")),['1','2','+','4','+'])
        self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("( 1 + 2 ) * 4 ;")),['1', '2', '+', '4', '*'])  
        self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("( 125 * ( ( 131 + 48 ) / 35 ) ) / 7.9  ;")),['125', '131', '48', '+', '35', '/', '*', '7.9', '/']) #ERROR 
        self.assertEqual(opn(tokenze("( 1 + 2 / x + y ) * 4 ;")),None)
    def exc(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError,opn(tokenze("1 + ( 2 + 4 ;"))) 
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError,opn(tokenze("1 +  2 + 4  ) + x  ;")))               

if __name__=="__main__":
    u.main()
```

Отлаживал,отлаживал,сюда пишу)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде решил)

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def tokenze(code:str)->list:
    return code.split() 
def op_prior(char_op:str):
    if char_op=="^":
        return 6
    elif char_op=="*":
        return 5
    elif char_op=="/":
        return 5
    elif char_op=="%":
        return 3
    elif char_op=="+":
        return 2
    elif char_op=="-":
        return 2 
def isOp(c:str)->bool:
    if c=="-" or c=="+" or c=="*" or c=="/" or c=="^" :return True
    return False   
def opn(code:str)->None: 
    p=0
    op_stack:list=[]
    res:list=[]
    while True: 
        v=code[p]
        p+=1
        if v==';':
            break 
        if re.match("[0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*",v) or re.match("[A-Za-z]+",v):
            res.append(v)
        elif isOp(v):
                while(len(op_stack)>0 and 
                op_stack[-1]!="(" and 
                op_prior(v)<=op_prior(op_stack[-1]) ):
                    res.append(op_stack.pop())
                  #if len(op_stack)==0: raise RuntimeError("No left paren")
                op_stack.append(v)       
        elif v==')':
            while len(op_stack)>0:
                x=op_stack.pop()
                if x=='(':
                    break
                res.append(x)
        elif v=="(":
            op_stack.append(v)                                                          
    while len(op_stack)>0 :
           res.append(op_stack.pop())
              #if op_stack[-1]=="(":
                  #raise RuntimeError("No right paren")            
    return res
```